Vanishing of higher morphisms for pair moduli
Consider a moduli scheme $P$ of sheaves $F$ on a Calabi-Yau n-fold $X$ with a section $s\in H^0(F)$. Alternatively, such objects can be described as maps $\mathcal{O}_X \xrightarrow{s} F$ called pairs. Take the universal pair $\mathcal{O}_{X\times P}\xrightarrow{\mathfrak{s}}\mathcal{F}$ on $X\times P$, and construct its push forward
$$
H^\bullet(\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes \mathcal{O}_P\xrightarrow{R\pi_*(\mathfrak{s})}R\pi_*(\mathcal{F})
$$
along the projection $\pi: X\times P\to P$. There is then a composition $\kappa$ of morphisms
$$
\mathcal{O}_P[-n]\cong H^n(\mathcal{O}_X)[-n]\otimes \mathcal{O}_P\to H^\bullet(\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes \mathcal{O}_P\xrightarrow{R\pi_*(\mathfrak{s})}R\pi_*(\mathcal{F})\,,
$$
where the first map is induced by the inclusion of the fourth cohomology group of $\mathcal{O}_X$.
Assuming that the family $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies $R^i\pi_*(\mathcal{F}) = 0$ for $i>0$ (i.e., $H^i(F)=0$ for $i>0$ for all such pairs $\mathcal{O}_X\to F$), is it true that $\kappa =0$ in the derived category of sheaves on $P$?
I tried taking all sorts of $\pi_*$-acyclic resolutions of $\mathcal{O}_{X\times P}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ and finding an actual morphism of complexes between them, but to no avail. At the same time, I did not see why this statement would be false.

This is not true in general. Consider, for instance, the moduli space of skyscraper sheaves on an elliptic curve $X$. Thus, $P = X$, $\mathcal{F} = \Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is the structure sheaf of the diagonal, and
$$
s \colon \mathcal{O}_{X \times X} \to \Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X
$$
is the natural morphism. Note that the induced morphism
$$
H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \oplus H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X) =
H^1(X \times X, \mathcal{O}_{X \times X}) \stackrel{s}\to 
H^1(X \times X, \Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X) = 
H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)
$$
is the summation; in particular, its restriction to each summand in the left-hand side is the identity. It remains to note that your composition morphism
$$
\mathcal{O}_X[-1] \to 
R\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{X \times X} \stackrel{R\pi_*s}\to 
R\pi_*\mathcal{F}
$$
corresponds by adjucntion to the composition
$$
\mathcal{O}_{X \times X} \stackrel{\pi^*\epsilon}\to
\mathcal{O}_{X \times X} \stackrel{s}\to
\Delta_*\mathcal{O}_X,
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the generator of $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$.

Thank you! Perhaps let me comment that this argument works very strict Calabi-Yau n-fold. Also, you don't need to use the adjunction at the end. The statement follows from unwrapping your $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}X) \oplus H^1(X, \mathcal{O}X) =
H^1(X \times X, \mathcal{O}{X \times X}) \stackrel{s}\to
H^1(X \times X, \Delta*\mathcal{O}_X) =
H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$.
